Call to dagster graph not finishing
I'm setting this raise error raise ValueError("Error").
When I run in terminal something like python main.py jobname argument1 it shows the error, but doesn't finish. Do you know what should need to be done to finish automatically? This is causing running jobs not finishing when fails, only when are successfull
